# Equal height columns that resize with the window

Tags: jquery, resize, height

I thought this markup should work, but it I must be doing something wrong. I have two divs that I want to be the same height and dynamically resize when the window is resized. One of the boxes becomes taller when the text inside the box wraps.

Edit: The two divs are side by side and I want the shorter one to resize to be the same height as the taller one. If the user has a device with a smaller screen or resizes the window to be smaller it causes the text in the  to wrap in one box before the other. I want them both to remain the same height regardless of how the user changes the size of the window.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('div.subFeaturedContainer > section').each(function() {

        var $sameHeightChildren = $(this).find('.subFeatured');
        var maxHeight = 0;

        $sameHeightChildren.each(function() {
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight());
        });

        $sameHeightChildren.css({ height: maxHeight + 'px' });

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="subFeaturedContainer">
    <section class="subFeatured">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <a href="#">Nam vel risus mauris, id lacinia nulla</a>
    </section>

    <section class="subFeatured">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <a href="#">Donec tincidunt tellus ac dolor tristique blandit. Nam vel iaculis lorem.</a>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.subFeatured {
width: 43.5%;
float: left;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
border-top: 1px solid #b1bdbe;
padding: 2% 3% 2% 3%;
}

.subFeatured:nth-child(even) {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more context? By "resize with the window" do you mean just when the document loads or when the user resizes the window? Can you provide code for the example you described with text overflowing?

Comment: do you have a CSS , if yes please post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but I ended up using a script that I found here:

http://www.tutrino.com/2011/12/08/equal-height-columns-with-jquery-jxcol-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove  `> section` : you're not finding the englobing element with the first selector.

See http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/Pzm8k/

Additionally, maybe you'd like to call your function with the jquery $(window).resize binding function too, so that the sections remain equal when you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it easily

```
   $(document).ready(function () { 

        maxHeight = 0;
        $('.subFeatured').each(function() {
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).outerHeight());
        });

        $('.subFeatured').css({ height: maxHeight + 'px' });  
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Late addition, but for future reference, on newer browsers you can use `flexbox` to achieve this.

Here's an example with 2 divs with the same height (**[FIDDLE HERE](http://cssdesk.com/72Z3Z)**)

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1">
    <p>I'm column one</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Here's my bottom text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">I'm just a small div</div>
</div>
```

---

## CSS

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

---

## References

- **[Comprehensive list of flexbox options](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**
- **[Browser support (caniuse flexbox)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)**